# How to run a program at boot time in the Guix system?

Tags: cron, guix

Guix implements mcron, a pretty nice "new" implementation of Paul Vixie's cron.  Time specifications such as @reboot are non-standard and it seems that mcron did not implement it.  However, mcron comes with a Guile API.  Is there some way to a command run at reboot?

Any alternative is also a solution, but it must be doable by regular users.  Maybe Guix itself offers a second, off-mcron solution to the problem?

Adding the line `@reboot echo hello` produces the following output after `crontab -e` exits.

```
%crontab -e
mcron: /tmp/crontab.2164:1: Bad job line in Vixie file.
Edit again?
```